# ksqlDB Java Client: Is it possible to deserialze the result of a ksqlDB query directly to a list of avro objects?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, deserialization, avro, ksqldb

I'm new to ksqlDB and wondering if the following is possible (java client):

My current situation is the following, I've:

- a working kafka infrastructure including the ksqlDB server and the (avro) schema registry
- some topics with already existing messages (using avro for serialization of values and String for keys)
- a ksqlDB stream which is created on top of an existing topic with *value_format='AVRO'*
- a SELECT query which already returns the correct data
- the *SHOW STREAMS;* command (in ksqlDB CLI) shows, that the stream is correctly configured and the value format is *AVRO*
- the avro schema is stored correctly in the schema registry
- the java classes of the avro objects are available on the classpath

My problem is, that the *SELECT* query returns a list of objects of type *Row* which contains *KsqlObjects* for each column and this objects also contain *KsqlObjects*, *KsqlArrays*, and *JsonArrays* for their attributes.

**Now I want to deserialize the content of one column directly to my (avro) object type.**

Is there either

- a deserializer for KsqlObject -> avro object?
- or any other why to execute the SELECT statement with returns the already deserialized avro objects?

Creating of my ksqlDB stream

```
CREATE STREAM cars WITH (kafka_topic='topic_cars', value_format='AVRO');
```

Execution of my SELECT statement (java client):

```
Client client = Client.create(options);
BatchedQueryResult batchedQueryResult = client.executeQuery(client, "SELECT * FROM CARS");
List<Row> resultRows = batchedQueryResult.get();
```

Current conversion to avro object - which is not very nice:

```
Row row = resultRows.get(0)
KsqlObject carColumn = row.getKsqlObject("CAR");
Car car = new Car();
car.setColor(row.getString("COLOR));
car.setType(row.getString("TYPE));
... (all other attributes, including complex data types)
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
Client client = Client.create(options);
AvroDeserializer deserializer = ...;
BatchedQueryResult batchedQueryResult = client.executeQuery(client, "SELECT * FROM CARS");
List<Row> resultRows = batchedQueryResult.get();
Row row = resultRows.get(0);
Car car = deserializer.deserialize(row.getColumn("CAR));
```

Is this possible?
If yes, how would the code look like?

Comment: If you want Avro objects, just use a Kafka consumer rather than a ksql client. Ksql already is deserializing the data, so it's no longer Avro at that point

Comment: So there is no chance to get it as avro object if using ksql?

Comment: As mentioned, the data is already deserialized, so no. You're just re-serializing it by pulling the fields into an Avro POJO type. Why not use a direct Kafka consumer?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
We do not use the kafka consumer directly because in our application the select statements are much more complicate as shown in the example above. Furthermore our application does not persist the data which is already available in the topic, therefore it is not so easy to implement a query with 'standard' consumers (at least as far as I know).

Comment: Without seeing your actual query, it's hard to know what you mean, but ksql is built over Kafka Streams API and Kafka Streams can do more that ksql can. And Kafka Consumer can do even more... I said nothing about persisting data elsewhere only that you don't really need Avro POJOs, but you will need to parse the Row objects to some other model if you continue to use ksql.